Are submetrizable semiregular spaces regular?
Definitions:
Let $X$ be a topological space.
$X$ is submetrizable if $X$ has a coarser metrizable topology.
$X$ is semiregular if $X$ has a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of open sets such that $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(O)) = O$ for every $O \in \mathcal{B}$.

I was looking for examples of submetrizable semiregular spaces that aren't regular in $\pi$-Base, but I haven't found any (*). Does anyone know an example of such, or are submetrizable semiregular spaces regular?

Here is an example: first, for each $n \geq 1$, let $I_n = [\frac{2}{3^n}, \frac{1}{3^{n-1}}]$ and $J_n = (\frac{2}{3^n}, \frac{1}{3^{n-1}})$. Let $A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ and $\widetilde{A} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty J_n$. Clearly, $\widetilde{A}$ is the interior of $A$ under the Euclidean topology. Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ be equipped with the topology $\tau$ generated by the closed subbasis consisting of all Euclidean-closed sets and $A$.
We first note that the topology on $X$ is stronger than the Euclidean topology, which is metrizable, so by definition $X$ is submetrizable. We also observe that, as $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ under the Euclidean topology, the topology on $X$ is the same as the Euclidean topology away from $0$. More precisely, if $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ is s.t. the closure of $B$ under the Euclidean topology does not contain $0$, then the closure of $B$ under $\tau$ coincides with its Euclidean closure; similarly, if $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ does not contain $0$, then the interior of $B$ under $\tau$ coincides with its Euclidean interior. Thus, for any $x \in X \setminus \{0\}$, $x$ has a neighborhood basis consisting of regular open sets, e.g., open intervals centered at $x$ of radii smaller than $|x|$.
We now consider neighborhoods of $0$. It is easy to see that the following is a neighborhood basis at $0$,
$$\{(-r, r) \cap A^c: r > 0, r \notin A\}$$
We claim that such $(-r, r) \cap A^c$ are regular open. To see this, first note that all closed sets under $\tau$ can be written as $K_1 \cap (K_2 \cup A)$, where $K_1, K_2$ are Euclidean-closed; or equivalently as $K_3 \cup (K_4 \cap A)$, where $K_3, K_4$ are Euclidean-closed. Hence, if $B \subset A^c$, we may write the closure of $B$ under $\tau$ as $K_3 \cup (K_4 \cap A)$, where $K_3, K_4$ are Euclidean-closed. As $K_4 \cap A \subset A$ is disjoint from $B \subset A^c$, we see that the closure of $B$ is simply $K_3$, i.e., the closure of $B$ under $\tau$ coincides with its Euclidean closure. Applied to the present case, we have the closure of $(-r, r) \cap A^c$ under $\tau$ is then,
$$[-r, r] \cap \widetilde{A}^c$$
To calculate the interior of the above, we take its complement,
$$([-r, r] \cap \widetilde{A}^c)^c = (-\infty, -r) \cup (r, \infty) \cup \widetilde{A}$$
The first two terms have their Euclidean closures away from $0$, so their closures under $\tau$ coincide with the Euclidean closures. For the final term $\widetilde{A}$, we may write its closure under $\tau$ as $K_1 \cap (K_2 \cup A)$, where $K_1, K_2$ are Euclidean-closed. Then $K_1$ is an Euclidean-closed set containing $\widetilde{A}$, from which we easily see $A \subset K_1$. Thus, $A \subset K_1 \cap (K_2 \cup A)$. As $A$ is closed under $\tau$, we have the closure of $\widetilde{A}$ under $\tau$ is $A$. Putting it together, the closure of $([-r, r] \cap \widetilde{A}^c)^c$ is therefore,
$$(-\infty, r] \cup [r, \infty) \cup A = [(-r, r) \cap A^c]^c$$
Hence, the interior of $[-r, r] \cap \widetilde{A}^c$ is $(-r, r) \cap A^c$, so $(-r, r) \cap A^c$ is indeed regular open. This concludes the proof that $X$ is semiregular.
Finally, we show that $X$ is not regular. Indeed, $A$ is closed in $X$ and $0 \notin A$. Assume to the contrary that the two are separated by open sets. Then there exists open $U$ s.t. $0 \in U$ and the closure of $U$ is disjoint from $A$. As we have noted before, $(-r, r) \cap A^c$ with $r > 0$, $r \notin A$ form a neighborhood basis for $0 \in X$, so we may assume WLOG that $U = (-r, r) \cap A^c$ for some $r > 0$, $r \notin A$. But its closure, as we have computed before, is $[-r, r] \cap \widetilde{A}^c$, which contains endpoints of $I_n$ for sufficiently large $n$ and thus intersects $A$, a contradiction. This shows $X$ is not regular.

Impressive example! Thank you so much, David Gao.
